# Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements? DOMException in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, encryption, backend

My Function

```
async function NewEncrypt(data, key)
  {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    //const KeyArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(key).buffer;
    const CryptoKeyObject = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", enc.encode(key).buffer, {"name": "AES-GCM"}, false, ['encrypt']);

    const encodedData = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
   const EncryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: 'AES-GCM'}, CryptoKeyObject, encodedData);
   //alert(EncryptedData);
  }
```

Calling the function

`NewEncrypt("1234", "5gfdgdfef");`

Yet I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements
    NewEncrypt file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/website/main_script.js:40
    <anonymous> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/website/main_script.js:2
main_script.js:40
    NewEncrypt file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/website/main_script.js:45
    AsyncFunctionThrow self-hosted:856
    (Async: async)
    <anonymous> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/website/main_script.js:2
```

It highlights the word const before CryptoKeyObject

I tried from the mozilla docs and chatgpt, reddit, and nothing worked

Comment: You are using a key length that is invalid for AES. In addition, the IV is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an "iv" Initialisation Vector , and use a 16 / 24 / 32 chars key :

```
function NewEncrypt(data, key) {
  const enc = new TextEncoder();
  const CryptoKeyObject = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw", 
    enc.encode(key), 
    { name: "AES-GCM" }, 
    false, 
    ['encrypt']
  );

  const encodedData = enc.encode(data);
  const encryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    { name: 'AES-GCM', iv: crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12)) },
    CryptoKeyObject,
    encodedData
  );

  return encryptedData;
}
```

use :

```
NewEncrypt("1234", "azeryuioqsdfhjkl")
```